# Weird "Switch Case" statement

Tags: objective-c, c, switch-statement

I have this piece of code in one of my file:

```
switch ([sender tag]){
    ...

    case 100:
        UIView *v1 = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame blabllabla...
        [v1  bla bla bla...
        break;
    ...
```

Looks pretty standard huh? But it gives me this error:

```
"Use of undeclared v1"
```

Then i put an "NSLog()" or "if" statement, like this:

```
case 100:
    NSLog(@"why need a nslog here?");
```

or

```
case 100:
    if(1==1) {
        ...
```

Then it works.

Anyone know why is that? Is it my code or objective-c rules?

Comment: This is nothing to do with Objective-C specifically; `label: declaration` is not in the standard C grammar from which Objective-C inherits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot declare variables whose scope is limited to a `case` without using a C block. Change it to:

```
case 100:
{
    UIView *v1 = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame blabllabla...
    [v1  bla bla bla...
    break;
}
```

and it should work.

Comment: WOWWWW... it works!! thanks man, i have been wondering about this for 1 hour, and i could not figure it out "why" LOL. Anyway, I need to wait 4 mins to choose for best answer. The best answer has been reserved for u =)

Comment: `case 100:; UIView *v1...` would work too. Look up the grammar of C, it's in the definition of labels. You couldn't put a goto label in front of a declaration either.

Comment: @tristopia Interesting. I’d never thought of `case` introducing a label but now that you’ve mentioned it makes sense.